# Integrate $\int x|J_1(x)|^2 \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, special-functions, bessel-functions

Hi I am trying to integrate:

$$
\int_0^R x|J_1(bx)|^2 \, dx,\quad R>0, b\in \mathbb{C}
$$
where $|J_1|^2=\bar{J}_1 J_1$ where $\bar{J_1}$ means complex conjugation of the bessel function.

My attempt was
$$
\int_0^R x J_1(bx) \bar{J_1}(bx) \, dx=\int_0^R x J_1(bx) J_1(\bar b x) \, dx.
$$
if we now define $c\equiv \bar b$ we can write
$$
\int_0^R x J_1(bx) {J_1}(\bar bx) \, dx=\int_0^R x J_1(bx) J_1(c x) \, dx,
$$
but this integral can be done and is given by:
$$
\int_0^R x J_1(bx) J_1(c x)dx=R\frac{cJ_1(bR)J_0(cR)-bJ_0(bR)J_1(cR)}{b^2-c^2}.
$$
Is this correct, if so, is there anyway to simplify this? If not, how can we do this integral?  Is it possible? I feel like if it is not correct, maybe it is not okay to use $c\equiv \bar b$ and proceed with the integration.  Thanks!!

Comment: @Dr.MV Woops. For some reason my mind replaced the first $R$ with an infinity.

Comment: @Dr.MV Do you mean the result I posted is not correct?  We specifically have $b=\bar c$, so the denominator is imaginary.  I am not sure what you mean by your suggestion to use L'hospitals rule.  I know how to use this rule, just not sure why this comes up.  Is this integral I did wrong?  Thanks for your help! (again)

Comment: @Dr.MV Okay, however, $b\neq c$, $b=\bar c$.  So is this result valid for $b=\bar c$?   For $b=c$, (which is a different case than this post), I will use L'hospitals rule to get the answer.  I may need this case at another time, so thanks for pointing that out.  If  I said anything incorrect, let me know.

Comment: @Dr.MV Do you know of anyway to simplify this?  I can easily use $c=\bar b$ and plug back in, just unsure of how to simplify from there, if possible.  Also, I think it is important to evaluate the case $b=c$ also as you pointed out, thanks.

Comment: @Dr.MV I would like to find out if the result is real or not, (it should be) so simplifying  the expression may help to see that.

Comment: Use $z-\bar z=2i\text{Im}(z)$ and $z+\bar z=2\text{Re}(z)$.  The numerator is in the form of the former (i.e.,.a complex quantity Minus its complex conjugate).  The. Denominator is of the form of a product of former and latter.  Both numerator and denominator are imaginary.

Comment: @Dr.MV That explains everything, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure